# Extra 50 lbs (23kg) bag with Air China

Tags: luggage, india, china

I am traveling from Qingdao, China to Mumbai, India on Air China for business. My ticket itinerary has 1 piece of luggage confirmed. However, I bought some additional items that I have to take back with me (clothes and gift merchandise).

Now, I have an extra bag weighing 50 lbs (23 kg). I contacted my travel agency and they said that the cost of an extra bag is approximately 650 - 800 RMB. I searched various websites but have not found information to confirm this.

How can I positively confirm the price? And can I pay for an additional bag in advance to avoid any last-minute formalities?

Comment: 20 seconds on google [found this page with domestic excess prices a link to a table of international ones](http://www.airchina.com/pk/en/travel_information/general_travelling_inforamtion/baggage_information/baggage_checked9.shtml), does that not cover what you need?

Comment: the word doc in the link @Gagravarr posted has the answer

Answer (score 2):

[Air China has a dedicated page on purchasing excess luggage](http://www.airchina.com.cn/vaservice/loginAction/loginIndex?language=en). There are a few restrictions including the availability of the service being only on non-codeshare flights. To date the price for one 23kg extra piece of luggage is 650`RMB`. Below is a screenshot from the linked website:

[image: AirChina Extra luggage]

Comment: If I understand it correctly, it says that this service is applicable for all flights departing from Beijing to North America. Am I missing out on something @JoErNanO

Comment: @AngryPanda Indeed. You might want to contact the airline for clarifications.